# Add initializing class that requires DI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I don't understand the way ASP.NET MVC initializes the application.
As far as I know, first it executes the code in `App_Start`, following the `Global.asax.cs` file, then the `Startup.cs` and finally it waits for incoming web requests.

### Scenario

Most applications are composed of one background layer that runs even if no one is accessing the web pages, and another that serves the HTTP requests. The first executes the core tasks of the systems: exchanges data with external devices, updates the database, reads/writes input/output files, etc... When someone connects to the webserver the "UI" layer will show the results in form of web pages.

(For the sake of simplicity, here I'm assuming the "core" layer is a class inside the ASP.NET project. Of course, for bigger applications it would be better to add a referenced project to keep the things clean, but it shouldn't make any difference about my question, I hope)

### Goal

The basic ASP.NET MVC template allows to configure the service required for the web layer, that are required only web the pages are requested.
Instead, **I need to add a further initialization of my underlying classes, once for the entire lifetime of the web application** (i.e. until the server is turned off).

### Trials

**First**
Reading the documentation, I thought the right place to put this initialization functions is the `App_Start` folder.I created my `Init` class with some methods to init the different sections.

Failure: because it needs a *static* class, it cannot have a constructor, hence I cannot inject the dependant classes (i.e. `DbContext`).

**Second**
I'm using `Hangfire`, so I tried to add a background job at the end of the `Application_Start()` function:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<Erp>(x => x.Init());
```

Failure: the `Application_Start()` function is executed *before* `Configuration()` one (in `Startup.cs`) hence `Hangfire` is not available yet.

**Third**
Well, what about to place the line above at the end of the `Configuration()` function?

Failure? No errors are generated but neither the constructor of my class, nor the requested method are executed.

For your reference, this is my `Erp` class (I copy here the relevant sections):

```
public interface IErp
{
    void Init();
    Task ImportOrdersAsync();
}

public class Erp : IErp
{  

    private readonly IMyContext _context;
    private readonly LiveData _liveData;

    public Erp(IMyContext context, LiveData liveData)
    {
        _context = context;
        _liveData = liveData;
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        _liveData.Plcs.Clear();
        var machines = _context.Machines.ToList();

        foreach (var machine in machines)
        {
            Plc plc = new Plc
            {
                Name = machine.Name,
                Description = machine.Description,
            };
            _liveData.Plcs.Add(plc);
        }
    }     

    public async Task ImportOrdersAsync()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

and here the `Ninject` services:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IMyContext>().To<MyContext>().InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<IErp>().To<Erp>().InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<LiveData>().To<LiveData>().InSingletonScope();
}
```

About the minimal and compilable example: it should be enough to add this example classes (no matter their contents) on the default MVC template.
Anyway, if I forgot any important piece of code, please tell me.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Short one: where put code to be executed on startup but *after * all dependencies and services are ready